# Rewrite insert() function - list index out of range

Tags: python, list, insert

I'm essentially trying to re-create a version of the `insert()` function for a homework assignment.
I've written the following function:

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    list_copy = []

    if insert_position < 0:
        insert_position = 0

    if insert_position >= len(my_list):
        insert_position = len(my_list) - 1

    i = 0
    while i < len(my_list) + 1:
        while i < insert_position:
            list_copy.append(my_list[i])
            i += 1

        while i == insert_position:
            list_copy.append(value)
            i += 1

        while i > insert_position:
            list_copy.append(my_list[i-1])
            i += 1

    return list_copy
```

I get the error `list index out of range` for the final while sub-loop, and I can't work out why. The while loop is accounting for the new list length (`while i < len(my_list) + 1`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is because you are using those nested while loops which *do not exit until their condition is false*. So the outer while loop check for `i` being less then the length of `my_list` doesn't happen until all nested while loops finish  (which it never does). Specifically I think the issue is with the last while loop here:

```
while i > insert_position:
    list_copy.append(my_list[i-1])
    i += 1
```

This while loop will not end because `i` will always be greater then the `insert_position` and eventually the `i` value will be outside the length of your `my_list`.

---

If you change your code logic to use `if` statements inside the while loop I think that will be better and then you only have to increase `i` once at the end:

```
i = 0
while i < len(my_list) + 1:
    if i < insert_position:
        list_copy.append(my_list[i])
    elif i == insert_position:
        list_copy.append(value)
    else:
        list_copy.append(my_list[i-1])

    i += 1
```

Comment: Marked as solution as it fixed the issue, but it has introduced (or revealed, more likely) a new problem. In the case where an item needs to be added to the end of the list, it adds it to the second last position instead. Why?

Comment: That is because in your check to make sure that the insert position isn't greater then the list, you need to set `insert_position = len(my_list)` instead of `len(my_list) - 1`. It's wrong because it sets the `insert_position` to be the second to last position instead of the end of the list like you expect.